# Adaptive Huffman coding and Canonical Huffman coding

Tags: algorithms

What is the complexity of adaptive Huffman code over canonical Huffman code? If encoder and decoder have exact knowledge of probability distribution of the source, then which scheme is optimal? Because adaptive Huffman coding require more computation while canonical Huffman coding require more memory.